# C++ passing instance variables byref are not updated

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I usually write C# and Objective C, but I am writing something in openframeworks in C++ and attempting to use Tweenzor to animate it, it works just fine if I put a variable in my class, e.g.
h

```
float mainX;
```

cpp

```
mainX = 100;
Tweenzor::add(&mainX, (float)mainX, (radius * 2), 0.0f, 2.5f);
```

but if I make a class called menuCircle, it says it finishes but nothing changes, I have a feeling it's incrementing something but not the instance variable in the class any idea how to call it by reference?  I've tried 15 different ways:
h

```
class menuCircle
{
    public:
        float x;
        float y;
        float r;
        ofColor c;
        void init(float xCoord, float yCoord, float radius);
        void move(float x, float y);
        void animate(float xCoord, float yCoord, float radius);
        void didFinish(float *e);
};
```

cpp

```
void menuCircle::animate(float xCoord, float yCoord, float radius){
    Tweenzor::add(&x, x, xCoord, 0.0f, 2.5f);
    Tweenzor::addCompleteListener( Tweenzor::getTween(&x), this, &menuCircle::didFinish);
    ofLog(OF_LOG_NOTICE, "tweening");

}
void menuCircle::didFinish(float *e){
    ofLog(OF_LOG_NOTICE, "tweening finished");
}
```

Comment: We at least need to see `add`.

Comment: It's too long, here https://github.com/NickHardeman/ofxTweenzor/blob/master/src/Tweenzor.cpp , line 101

Comment: @fizgig there's lots of `add` functions there. All we need is the prototype and how you're calling it. That's two lines.

Comment: Do you know the difference between pointers and references? "byref" is not a c++ term and your usage could mean either. Also please edit the question with only the relevant function call along with the declarations of variables used, which argument you're having trouble with, and what you WANT it to do.

Comment: I meant by reference.  If I get rid of everything else I typed out and just post the 2 lines, I would not have the issue I am having, as I said, if I just use the variables directly in my main class, it works fine, if I make a sub class and try to call a function inside of it to run the tween, it doesn't work.  It seems completely baffling to me as it's basically the exact same code and the finish function runs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You've left out all relevant pieces of code from your question, so here's how you generally pass something by reference:

```
void foo(int& bar) {
    bar = 3;
}

int x = 0;
foo(x);
// x == 3
```

The usual mistake is to put `&` in the wrong place. I suspect you're using it in the `address-of` sense, but again that's all speculation until you show what your `add` prototype is and how you're calling it.

Comment: calling 
`static void add(float* a_property, float a_begin, float a_end, int a_delay, int a_duration, int a_easeType=EASE_LINEAR, float a_p=0, float a_a=0);`

by 
`Tweenzor::add(&x, x, xCoord, 0.0f, 2.5f);`
where x is an instance variable of a class menuCircle like in my post above.  I've this->x and &this->x as well, same result.

Comment: Which argument do you want to pass by reference? `x`? Also, don't bury crucial information like this in the comments. Edit the question. While you're at it remove all the irrelevant code snippets.

Comment: I thought it was bad form to edit the original question.  Yes, x, sorry I thought the main issue was the fact that it's inside of another class hence the lengthy code post.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to edit the question for any reason from fixing typos/formatting to adding additional information or simply making it more clear. If you make a substantial change it's good form to note that you edited it and notify interested parties.

Comment: class membership makes no difference. It's important that you post the declarations of all the variables and functions so we can tell what they are. `x` is ambiguous unless we know it's a `float`. The more other crap you include the more difficult it is for someone to come and tell you your problem.